# Switch automatically between normal and insert mode in vim

Tags: vim

I am new to vim and have installed [oh-my-vim](https://github.com/liangxianzhe/oh-my-vim) and learnt these keybindings by googling:

> Jump forward by word - w
>
> Jump forward by word - b
>
> Jump to end of sentence - A
>
> Close current file without exiting - bd
>
> Undo is u
>
> Execute shell command with ! (bang)

of these typing Shift + a in Normal mode allows me to jump to end of sentence and also goes into insert mode soon as I start typing after it. I tried out Shift + w and Shift + b and
it also shows similar behaviour of going to insert mode as soon as I start typing after I use that keybinding.

What are the equivalents for these keybindings where I am not using a letter?

> Jump to start of sentence - 0
>
> Redo is Ctrl + R
>
> Jump to previous line - ``

Hope I am clear in describing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm also a beginner and I am getting used to Vim recently.

Well, regarding your question, to switch from **Normal to Insert**, you could press:

- `i` to **i**nsert (the cursor stays, effectively inserting to the left)
- `a` to **a**ppend (the cursor jumps after the character you were on)
- `I` to insert from the beginning of the line. This is equivalent to pressing `0` in Normal mode, and then pressing `i` to enter Insert mode.
- `A` to append to the end of the line. This is equivalent to pressing `$` in Normal mode to get to the end of the line, and then pressing `a` to append in Insert Mode.

For **Insert to Normal**:

- press `<Esc>` to get to Normal mode.
- press `<Ctrl-[>` to get to Normal mode.
- press `<Ctrl-O>` to temporarily enter Normal mode for one command. Upon execution it will automatically return to Insert mode.

Personally, to shift between Normal mode, I use `<Ctrl-[>` for consecutive commands in Normal mode and `<Ctrl-O>` if it's a one time deal. `<Esc>` is too far for my pinky :)

Comment: Oops... Didn't realize at all this was asked ages ago. I'd imagine you're way beyond a beginner in Vim now. My apologies!

Comment: Correction: `I` is not equivalent to pressing `0` and `i`. It's equivalent to pressing `_` and `i`.

Additionally, `<C-c>` also exits Insert mode but without checking for abbreviations and without triggering `InsertLeave`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking. `Shift+W` and `Shift+B` do not automatically enter insert mode, instead they go back and forth on WORDS (vs words).

If you want to enter insert mode, just hit `i`. You could hit `wi` to insert after a word.

You mention `0`, which goes to the beginning of a line. You can hit `I` (shift+I) to insert at the beginning of a line. Note that this inserts after the initial whitespace on the line, it is the same as hitting `^i`. If you want to insert at the very beginning of the line, you'll need to use `0i`.